# Trying to create a dynamic cascading list

Tags: xslt, symphony-cms

So I have this data for a client ( see below ) and I want to create a bulleted list that can have any number of tiers. I also want it to be dynamic in the aspect that items can be listed more than once. The CMS is set up so a TAG will claim its parents. Wherever a TAG claims its parents, its children should replicate beneath. Not sure how to tackle this with XSLT, but a simple example should end up looking something like this..

```
<ul>
    <li>Missions</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Kampala, Uganda</li>
            <li>Lima, Peru</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If `Kampala, Uganda` also claimed something else as a parent, it would appear multiple times. If `Kampala, Uganda` had other TAGS that claimed it as a parent, these children would cascade beneath `Kampala, Uganda` in each instance.

```
<data>
<tags>
    <section id="3" handle="tags">Tags</section>
    <entry id="72">
        <parents>
            <item handle="meetings">Meetings</item>
        </parents>
        <tag handle="bible-studies">Bible studies</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="51">
        <parents>
            <item handle="missions">Missions</item>
        </parents>
        <tag handle="brazil">Brazil</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="31">
        <parents>
            <item handle="ministry">Ministry</item>
        </parents>
        <tag handle="childrens-ministry">Children's ministry</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="28">
        <parents>
            <item handle="ministry">Ministry</item>
        </parents>
        <tag handle="college-and-career-ministry">College and Career ministry</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="56">
        <parents>
            <item handle="the-islands-of-vanuatu">The Islands of Vanuatu</item>
        </parents>
        <tag handle="fanafo-christian-fellowship">Fanafo Christian Fellowship</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="29">
        <parents>
            <item handle="ministry">Ministry</item>
        </parents>
        <tag handle="high-school-ministry">High School ministry</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="48">
        <parents>
            <item handle="missions">Missions</item>
        </parents>
        <tag handle="holsbybrunn-sweden">Holsbybrunn, Sweden</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="22">
        <tag handle="home">Home</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="19">
        <tag handle="israel">Israel</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="30">
        <parents>
            <item handle="ministry">Ministry</item>
        </parents>
        <tag handle="junior-high-ministry">Junior High ministry</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="47">
        <parents>
            <item handle="missions">Missions</item>
        </parents>
        <tag handle="kampala-uganda">Kampala, Uganda</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="49">
        <parents>
            <item handle="missions">Missions</item>
        </parents>
        <tag handle="lima-peru">Lima, Peru</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="64">
        <parents>
            <item handle="" />
        </parents>
        <tag handle="meetings">Meetings</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="32">
        <parents>
            <item handle="ministry">Ministry</item>
        </parents>
        <tag handle="men-s-ministry">Men’s ministry</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="44">
        <parents>
            <item handle="" />
        </parents>
        <tag handle="ministry">Ministry</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="33">
        <tag handle="missions">Missions</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="54">
        <parents>
            <item handle="the-islands-of-vanuatu">The Islands of Vanuatu</item>
        </parents>
        <tag handle="natanara-christian-fellowship">Natanara Christian Fellowship</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="50">
        <parents>
            <item handle="missions">Missions</item>
        </parents>
        <tag handle="ouagadougou-burkina-faso">Ouagadougou, Burkina Faso</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="46">
        <parents>
            <item handle="missions">Missions</item>
        </parents>
        <tag handle="the-islands-of-vanuatu">The Islands of Vanuatu</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="77">
        <parents>
            <item handle="missions">Missions</item>
        </parents>
        <tag handle="villahermosa-mexico">Villahermosa, Mexico</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="27">
        <parents>
            <item handle="ministry">Ministry</item>
        </parents>
        <tag handle="womens-ministry">Women's ministry</tag>
    </entry>
    <entry id="73">
        <parents>
            <item handle="meetings">Meetings</item>
        </parents>
        <tag handle="worship">Worship</tag>
    </entry>
</tags>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a little bit simpler and shorter solution (not requiring parameters at all) than that of @Alejandro. :)

Comment: @Kirk-Strobeck: I have updated my answer and now the correct result is produced when a `tag` has more than one parent. Again, it is simpler and shorter, doesn't use any parameters and is based on some fundamental features of `<xsl:key>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the children of an item to be wrapped in another `<li>`.

**This transformation** (quite similar to that of @Alejandro, but simpler, shorter and not requiring any parameters at all):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="kChildren" match="tag"
               use="string(../parents/item/@handle)"/>

    <xsl:key name="kChildren" match="tag"
               use="../parents/item/@handle"/>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="buildChildrenList">
        <xsl:variable name="vChildren" select=
        "key('kChildren', string(@handle))"/>

        <xsl:if test="$vChildren">
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$vChildren"/>
            </ul>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tag">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:call-template name="buildChildrenList"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the referred to source XML document:**

```
<data>
    <tags>
        <section id="3" handle="tags">Tags</section>
        <entry id="72">
            <parents>
                <item handle="meetings">Meetings</item>
            </parents>
            <tag handle="bible-studies">Bible studies</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="51">
            <parents>
                <item handle="missions">Missions</item>
            </parents>
            <tag handle="brazil">Brazil</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="31">
            <parents>
                <item handle="ministry">Ministry</item>
            </parents>
            <tag handle="childrens-ministry">Children's ministry</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="28">
            <parents>
                <item handle="ministry">Ministry</item>
            </parents>
            <tag handle="college-and-career-ministry">College and Career ministry</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="56">
            <parents>
                <item handle="the-islands-of-vanuatu">The Islands of Vanuatu</item>
            </parents>
            <tag handle="fanafo-christian-fellowship">Fanafo Christian Fellowship</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="29">
            <parents>
                <item handle="ministry">Ministry</item>
            </parents>
            <tag handle="high-school-ministry">High School ministry</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="48">
            <parents>
                <item handle="missions">Missions</item>
            </parents>
            <tag handle="holsbybrunn-sweden">Holsbybrunn, Sweden</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="22">
            <tag handle="home">Home</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="19">
            <tag handle="israel">Israel</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="30">
            <parents>
                <item handle="ministry">Ministry</item>
            </parents>
            <tag handle="junior-high-ministry">Junior High ministry</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="47">
            <parents>
                <item handle="missions">Missions</item>
            </parents>
            <tag handle="kampala-uganda">Kampala, Uganda</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="49">
            <parents>
                <item handle="missions">Missions</item>
            </parents>
            <tag handle="lima-peru">Lima, Peru</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="64">
            <parents>
                <item handle="" />
            </parents>
            <tag handle="meetings">Meetings</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="32">
            <parents>
                <item handle="ministry">Ministry</item>
            </parents>
            <tag handle="men-s-ministry">Men’s ministry</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="44">
            <parents>
                <item handle="" />
            </parents>
            <tag handle="ministry">Ministry</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="33">
            <parents>
                <item handle="" />
            </parents>
            <tag handle="missions">Missions</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="54">
            <parents>
                <item handle="the-islands-of-vanuatu">The Islands of Vanuatu</item>
            </parents>
            <tag handle="natanara-christian-fellowship">Natanara Christian Fellowship</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="50">
            <parents>
                <item handle="missions">Missions</item>
            </parents>
            <tag handle="ouagadougou-burkina-faso">Ouagadougou, Burkina Faso</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="46">
            <parents>
                <item handle="junior-high-ministry">Junior High ministry</item>
                <item handle="missions">Missions</item>
            </parents>
            <tag handle="the-islands-of-vanuatu">The Islands of Vanuatu</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="77">
            <parents>
                <item handle="missions">Missions</item>
            </parents>
            <tag handle="villahermosa-mexico">Villahermosa, Mexico</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="27">
            <parents>
                <item handle="ministry">Ministry</item>
            </parents>
            <tag handle="womens-ministry">Women's ministry</tag>
        </entry>
        <entry id="73">
            <parents>
                <item handle="meetings">Meetings</item>
            </parents>
            <tag handle="worship">Worship</tag>
        </entry>
    </tags>
</data>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Israel</li>
    <li>Meetings
        <ul>
            <li>Bible studies</li>
            <li>Worship</li>
        </ul></li>
    <li>Ministry
        <ul>
            <li>Children's ministry</li>
            <li>College and Career ministry</li>
            <li>High School ministry</li>
            <li>Junior High ministry
                <ul>
                    <li>The Islands of Vanuatu
                        <ul>
                            <li>Fanafo Christian Fellowship</li>
                            <li>Natanara Christian Fellowship</li>
                        </ul></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li>Men’s ministry</li>
            <li>Women's ministry</li>
        </ul></li>
    <li>Missions
        <ul>
            <li>Brazil</li>
            <li>Holsbybrunn, Sweden</li>
            <li>Kampala, Uganda</li>
            <li>Lima, Peru</li>
            <li>Ouagadougou, Burkina Faso</li>
            <li>The Islands of Vanuatu
                <ul>
                    <li>Fanafo Christian Fellowship</li>
                    <li>Natanara Christian Fellowship</li>
                </ul></li>
            <li>Villahermosa, Mexico</li>
        </ul></li>
</ul>
```

**Do note**:  This solution works correctly when a `tag` has more than one parent.

**Explanation**:

1. The  key:

`<xsl:key name="kChildren" match="tag"`
`use="string(../parents/item/@handle)"/>`

produces all the "children" from the string value of the `handle` attribute of the *first* (only) `item` child of their `parents` sibling. This covers also such `tag` elements that don't have any `parents` sibling (in which case the key value is the empty string).

.2. A second key with the same name:

```
<xsl:key name="kChildren" match="tag"
           use="../parents/item/@handle"/>
```

matches a `tag` by the value of *any* `handle`  attribute of the `item` child of their `parents` sibling. This makes it possible to have the `tag` listed for all "parents", not only for the first.

As we see here, the ability to have multiple keys with the same name is a very powerful and useful feature.

Comment: Works great, and much shorter!

Comment: I have integrated it, but there was only one question.. It doesn't seem to duplicate in each instance of a UL. For example, if The Islands of Vanuatu claimed both Missions and Junior High ministry as parents.. Here is a data set that reflects the example see.weareinto.com/525q

Comment: Simply astounding! what an elegant solution. Thank you!

Comment: @Kirk-Strobeck: I added an explanation. I also deleted an unnecessary `xsl:key` that was forgotten there from a previous version. The solution is now 3 lines shorter. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Multiple parents relationship added.

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kTagByParent"
             match="tag"
             use="../parents/item/@handle"/>
    <xsl:template match="/" name="makeUL">
        <xsl:param name="pChilds"
                   select="*/*/entry[not(parents/item/@handle!='')]/tag"/>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$pChilds"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tag">
        <xsl:variable name="vChilds" select="key('kTagByParent',@handle)"/>
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="@handle"/>
        </li>
        <xsl:if test="$vChilds">
            <li>
                <xsl:call-template name="makeUL">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pChilds" select="$vChilds"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </li>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<ul>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>israel</li>
    <li>meetings</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>bible-studies</li>
            <li>worship</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>ministry</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>childrens-ministry</li>
            <li>college-and-career-ministry</li>
            <li>high-school-ministry</li>
            <li>junior-high-ministry</li>
            <li>men-s-ministry</li>
            <li>womens-ministry</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>missions</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>brazil</li>
            <li>holsbybrunn-sweden</li>
            <li>kampala-uganda</li>
            <li>lima-peru</li>
            <li>ouagadougou-burkina-faso</li>
            <li>the-islands-of-vanuatu</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>fanafo-christian-fellowship</li>
                    <li>natanara-christian-fellowship</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>villahermosa-mexico</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

With the new provided input at http://see.weareinto.com/525q , output:

```
<ul>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>israel</li>
    <li>meetings</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>bible-studies</li>
            <li>worship</li>
        </ul></li>
    <li>ministry</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>childrens-ministry</li>
            <li>college-and-career-ministry</li>
            <li>high-school-ministry</li>
            <li>junior-high-ministry</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>the-islands-of-vanuatu</li>
                    <li>
                        <ul>
                            <li>fanafo-christian-fellowship</li>
                            <li>natanara-christian-fellowship</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>men-s-ministry</li>
            <li>womens-ministry</li>
        </ul></li>
    <li>missions</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>brazil</li>
            <li>holsbybrunn-sweden</li>
            <li>kampala-uganda</li>
            <li>lima-peru</li>
            <li>ouagadougou-burkina-faso</li>
            <li>the-islands-of-vanuatu</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>fanafo-christian-fellowship</li>
                    <li>natanara-christian-fellowship</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>villahermosa-mexico</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Note**: Node set key value, new expression to get the roots.

Comment: That is a great solution! Thanks so much! I'll have to look thru your method to learn. I have integrated it, but there was only one question.. It doesn't seem to duplicate in each instance of a UL. For example, if `The Islands of Vanuatu` claimed both `Missions` and `Junior High ministry` as parents.. Here is a data set that reflects the example http://see.weareinto.com/525q